# What's the correct way to show/hide views in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm finally switching from jQuery to ReactJS, which is causing me to rethink some of the fundamentals.

In this case, I have a dashboard with three views and three corresponding navigation buttons. When I click one of these buttons, I want to show the corresponding view and hide the other two views.

Programmatically speaking, this is easy, but I want to make sure I'm "thinking in React" and learning the correct methodology.

This code works but seems bloated. Any advice?

```
var Views = React.createClass({
changeView: function (event) {
    var view = $(event.target).text();
    if(view == 'Audience') {
        this.setState({
            displayAudience: true,
            displayMetrics: false,
            displaySettings: false
        })
    }
    if(view == 'Metrics') {
        this.setState({
            displayAudience: false,
            displayMetrics: true,
            displaySettings: false
        })
    }
    if(view == 'Settings') {
        this.setState({
            displayAudience: false,
            displayMetrics: false,
            displaySettings: true
        })
    }
},
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        displayAudience: true,
        displayMetrics: false,
        displaySettings: false
    };
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="table">
            <div className="cell top col-15">
                <ul className="navigation">
                    <li onClick={this.changeView}>Audience</li>
                    <li onClick={this.changeView}>Metrics</li>
                    <li onClick={this.changeView}>Settings</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="cell top col-85 view">
                { this.state.displayAudience ? <Audience /> : null }
                { this.state.displayMetrics ? <Metrics /> : null }
                { this.state.displaySettings ? <Settings /> : null }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at react-router: https://github.com/rackt/react-router

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A library like react-router would be a more full featured solution but might be overkill for your use case. Your example can be simplified a fair bit by remembering that react components are basically javascript objects.

```
var Views = React.createClass({
changeView: function (viewComponent) {
    this.setState({
        currentView: viewComponent
    });
},
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        currentView: <Audience/>
    };
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="table">
            <div className="cell top col-15">
                <ul className="navigation">
                    <li onClick={this.changeView.bind(null, <Audience/>)}>Audience</li>
                    <li onClick={this.changeView.bind(null, <Metrics/>)}>Metrics</li>
                    <li onClick={this.changeView.bind(null, <Settings/>)}>Settings</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="cell top col-85 view">
                {this.state.currentView}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! I'll check out react-router at some point but believe it would be overkill for this project. Thanks!

Comment: +1, this is a good solution, though I generally recommend storing primitives in state and branching view logic off that. One of the big upshots of this is you can inspect and modify the state in the browser with the Reacat Dev Tools, or serialize it/get it from props/etc. more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this in your `render` function:

```
render: function () {
    var child = this.state.showP ? (<p></p>) : ();
    return (
        <div>
            {child}
        </div>
    );
}
```